# Creating pivot table (columns to rows) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, stock

I would like to create a pivot table from a PostgreSQL table below. (Also link: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hpjbQu2O))

```
CREATE TABLE sf1
    ("calendardate" varchar(10), "ticker" varchar(4), "revenueusd" int);
INSERT INTO sf1
    ("calendardate", "ticker", "revenueusd")
VALUES
('12/2021', 'DIS', '218190'),
('12/2021', 'ADBE', '41100'),
('12/2021', 'AAPL', '1239450'),
('03/2022', 'AAPL', '972780'),
('03/2022', 'DIS', '192490'),
('03/2022', 'ADBE', '42620'),
('06/2022', 'ADBE', '43860'),
('06/2022', 'AAPL', '829590'),
('06/2022', 'DIS', '215040')
```

```
SELECT 
    calendardate,
    ticker,
    revenueusd
FROM
    sf1
ORDER BY calendardate ASC
```

The code result looks like this:

| date | ticker | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/2021 | DIS | 218190 |
| 12/2021 | ADBE | 41100 |
| 12/2021 | AAPL | 1239450 |
| 03/2022 | AAPL | 972780 |
| 03/2022 | DIS | 192490 |
| 03/2022 | ADBE | 42620 |
| 06/2022 | ADBE | 43860 |
| 06/2022 | AAPL | 829590 |
| 06/2022 | DIS | 215040 |

The goal would be to transform it like this:

| ticker/date | 12/2021 | 03/2022 | 06/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DIS | 218190 | 192490 | 215040 |
| ADBE | 41100 | 42620 | 43860 |
| AAPL | 1239450 | 972780 | 829590 |

Is there any way to wire this while the final ticker rows and date columns also would change in number?

The data comes from [Nasdaq, Core US Fundamentals Data](https://data.nasdaq.com/databases/SF1/data)

Answer (score 0):

Refer query below -

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab('select  ticker, to_date(date1,''mm/yyyy'') date1,
     revenue from sf1 order by 1 desc,2 ')
    AS ct("ticker/date" text,
          "12/2021" integer,
          "03/2022" integer,
          "06/2022" integer);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BO__kaWs).